# Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize

Tags: tensorflow, keras, cudnn

I am trying to learn VGG16 model. But now, I got an error like,

> Using TensorFlow backend.
>   UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably
>   because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning
>   log message was printed above.     [[{{node conv2d_1/convolution}} =
>   Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1],
>   padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](conv2d_1/convolution-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer,
>   conv2d_1/kernel/read)]]    [[{{node dense_3/Softmax/_211}} =
>   _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_237_dense_3/Softmax",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

Here are my system versions,

- Windows 10
- Tensorflow 1.10.0
- Python 3.6.7
- cuDNN and CUDA;
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050TI
- Keras, Using TensorFlow backend.2.2.4

> nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA
>   Corporation Built on Fri_Sep__1_21:08:32_Central_Daylight_Time_2017
>   Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.176

If you need the code;

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import cv2, numpy as np


def VGG_16(weights_path=None):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1), input_shape=(224, 224, 3), data_format='channels_last'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2), data_format='channels_last'))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2), data_format='channels_last'))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2), data_format='channels_last'))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2), data_format='channels_last'))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2), data_format='channels_last'))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1000, activation='softmax'))

    if weights_path:
        model.load_weights(weights_path)

    return model

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from keras.applications.vgg16 import decode_predictions
    im = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('karisik_meyveler.jpg'), (224, 224)).astype(np.float32)
    im[:,:,0] -= 103.939
    im[:,:,1] -= 116.779
    im[:,:,2] -= 123.68
    im = im.transpose((1,0,2))
    im = np.expand_dims(im, axis=0)

    # Test pretrained model
    model = VGG_16('vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5')
    sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy')
    out = model.predict(im)
    predictions = decode_predictions(out)
```

The error pops up;

```
UnknownError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9b64406a16ce> in <module>()
     69     sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
     70     model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy')
---> 71     out = model.predict(im)
     72     predictions = decode_predictions(out)
```

Comment: Where exactly does the error pop up? Please remove any code that comes *after* that point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Check the updates for the NVIDIA drivers and update it.